# JS/HTML - How to write to the body of document multiple lines of text using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is my code so far

```js
var items = [];
function addItems () {
  items.push(document.getElementById("txtArea").value);
  document.getElementById('txtArea').value = '';
  console.log('items = [' + items + ']');
}

function displayItems () {
  var tag1 = '<p>',
      tag2 = '</p>';
  for(var i in items) {
    document.write(tag1 + 'Element ' + i + ' = ' + items[i] + tag2);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtArea'>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" onclick='addItems()'>
<input type="button" value="Display" id="displayButton" onclick='displayItems()'><hr>
<p id='elements'></p>
```

In the text field I add numbers that are pushed to an array. When I press display it should display all the elements of that array after the horizontal line, but instead it opens a new page with all of those elements.

What I want is to display elements after the horizontal line in the same page. Could someone please help me?

Comment: NEVER document.write after load. The page is wiped when you do

Comment: Ah, I see the script is still in the body. I am used to JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` will erase all data in body so you cannot use it after load.

Try to make a text var,

```
var text = "";
```

then append in loop

```
text += tag1 + 'Element ' + i + ' = ' + items[i] + tag2
```

At the end do

```
document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: That will ALSO wipe the script. The script needs to be in the head then

Comment: Even if the script is placed in the head section the result is loaded in a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text of paragraph `elements`

```
document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML = 'New Value';
```

instead of

```
document.write(....)
```

```js
var items = [];
function addItems() {
  items.push(document.getElementById("txtArea").value);
  document.getElementById('txtArea').value = '';
  console.log('items = [' + items + ']');
}

function displayItems() {
  var tag1 = '<p>',
    tag2 = '</p>',
    str = '';

  for (var i in items) {
    str += tag1 + 'Element ' + i + ' = ' + items[i] + tag2 + '<br/>';
  }
  document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtArea'>
<input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" onclick='addItems()'>
<input type="button" value="Display" id="displayButton" onclick='displayItems()'>
<hr>
<p id='elements'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, I believe you can do something like this, unfortunately i do not have time to try it myself.

```
var bodytag = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
for(var i in items) {
    var e = document.createElement('p');
    e.innerHTML = 'Element ' + i + ' = ' + items[i]
    bodytag.appendChild(e);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I managed to get it work using this example from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_body_append .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using this example from w3schools: [w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_body_app‌​end](http://w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_body_app%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bend) .

I've deleted the `<p id='elements'></p>` tag from the html code and modified the `displayItems` function like this:

```
function displayItems () {
    for(var i in items) {
    var e = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode('Element ' + i + ' = ' + items[i]);
    e.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    }
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].html = sth;
```

instead of:

```
document.write..
```